# phpmyadmin - clicking on item gives different view

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I click on any item in PhpMyAdmin, it gives a view like the attached image. What I have done to change working? How to re-set to work properly

thanks

Screen  shot:
[image]

Comment: It looks like missing some `CSS` files? look at the web console output (In Chrome: Menu->[More tools]->[Developer tools])

Comment: Can you explain further what I should be looking for and how to correct my mistakes? Phymyadmin was working properly. I can't remember what I did that made it behave like this. Thanks

Comment: I mean: hit the `F12` key in Chrome, you will see the web console, reload/refresh the `phpmyadmin` page,  and watch if there some errors appear, and post here to analyze.

Comment: There are no errors. But under "sources" - themes, phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=xxxx does not appear until I click "reload" for Chrome and the proper phpmyadmin view appears.